# Generating Combinations

Tags: c#, .net, console, combinations

Recently I have been reading about lotto wheeling and combination generating. I thought I'd give it a whirl and looked about for example code. I managed to cobble together a number wheel based on some VB but I've introduced an interesting bug while porting it.
http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=168296

It allows you to basically ID any combination. You feed it N numbers, K picks and an index and it returns that combination in lexicographical order.
It works well at low values but as the number of balls (N) rises I get additional numbers occurring for example. 40 balls, 2 picks. Combination No. 780  Returns 40 and 41! The more picks and numbers I added the higher this goes, It seem to happen at the end of a run when the number preceding is due to cycle.

I found the method for generating number of possible combination on the VB forum to not make a lot of sense, so I found a simpler one:
http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2334.htm
Then I discovered that using doubles seems to cause a lack of resolution. Using long works, but now I can't use higher values of N because the multiplying goes out of range for a long! I then tried ulong and decimal neither could go much past 26-28 numbers (N).
So I reverted to the version on the VB site.
http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?s=6548354125cb4f312fc555dd0864853e&t=129902

The code is a method to avoid hitting the 96bit ceiling and claims to be able to calculate as high as N 98, K 49. 
For some reason I cannot get this to behave, it spits out some very strange numbers.

After giving up for a while I decided to re-read the wiki suggested. While most of it was over my head, I was able to discover that certain ways of calculating a binomial coefficient have inaccuracy. This wouldn't be appropriate for a system where you are essentially dialing up (wheeling) to a game. After a bit of searching and reading I came across this:
http://dmitrybrant.com/2008/04/29/binomial-coefficients-stirling-numbers-csharp

Turns out this is exactly the information I was looking for! The first method is accurate and plenty fast for anything I'm doing. Much thanks for psYchotic going to the trouble of joining just to post here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are exactly 780 combinations of 2 numbers to generate out of a set of 40. If your combination generator uses a zero-based index, any index >= the maximum amount of combinations would be invalid.
You can use the [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) to determine the number of combinations that can be formed.

Comment: @Trinnexx - Modify the original question.

Comment: Most of that article is way over my head. Turns out the method at the end works, but also has floating point inaccuracies. However searching for binomial coefficient in general led to an article about calculating them with accuracy.
http://dmitrybrant.com/2008/04/29/binomial-coefficients-stirling-numbers-csharp
This method for combinations works past 45 (N) cheers for the lead.

Comment: Regarding your flag, please use the same e-mail for this account as your other and I can quickly merge the two. Flag again once you have.